# Google shared drive file missing

Tags: drive

Hey guys as can see in the screenshot below, one of my files went missing from the shared drive all of a sudden. Has anyone ever experienced the same thing? How do i solve this? I have really important docs in there and i need to recover them.

[Screenshot of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4brm2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Shared files are owned by another user. It's gets deleted from everywhere if owner of that shared file decides to delete it, or if owner revokes the permission.

It is simply deleted from your drive because owner deleted the file or owner revoked your permission to access that file.